# Linq Manipulate Output

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I want to manipulate the data output of my Linq Group by, taking out the Id's and only the results on the output not the group by Id's

How can i do this?

**This is my LINQ**

```
 foreach (var item in db.Pos.Where(r => r.Fecha.Day <= today.Day)
                       .Select(g => new { Pdv = g.Pdv, Total = g.Total })
                       .GroupBy(l => l.Pdv)
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(z => new { Pdv = z.Key, Total = z.Sum(l => l.Total) })
                       .OrderByDescending(r => r.Total)
                       .Select(r => new { Pdv = r.Pdv, Total = String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}", Decimal.Round(r.Total, 0)) })


        {
            listadepuntos.Add(item.ToString());
        }
```

**My output is like this:**

```
{Pdv = Central, Total = 42,143.00}
```

I want to take the "PDV=" part of my output and get only this:

```
{Central, Total = 42,143.00}
```

Is there a way to do this with my Linq? or some other extra code?

Comment: Just use `listadepuntos.Add(string.Format("{{{0}, Total = {1}}}", item. Pdv, item. Total))`

Comment: Looks like @Artuno suffering with this problem since morning.:-)

Comment: your right @HariPrasad i was suffering but this worked perfectly omg thank you very much :')

Comment: No worries, as @Rob advised in the last post, upvote/close the solutions that helped you.

Comment: Created solution as an answer to help people having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) to format the string before adding it to `List`

```
listadepuntos.Add(string.Format("{{{0}, Total = {1}}}", item. Pdv, item. Total));
```

If you are using `C# 6` then we can leverage beauty of [`String Interpolation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn961160.aspx).

```
listadepuntos.Add($"{{{item.Pdv}, Total = {item.Total}}}");
```